# Playback over UPNP (provided by miniDLNA) stops when new file added

Tags: vlc

I'm using my raspberry pi successfully as UPNP server with miniDLNA (aka ReadyMedia) and VLC as player on my desktop computer. I also have a transmission client running on the RP that once in a while adds new files to a folder indexed by miniDLNA.

Whenever this happens, VLC stops playing and I have to restart playback, then seek manually to the place where I was before.

Is there some configuration that I missed? Is this an issue with miniDLNA or rather VLC?

Thanks for your answers already in advance.